# Angular 2 : bind two input fields

Tags: html, angular

I have two inputs of type file. I want to sync those two inputs, such that when I select an image in the first input, it will be automatically added to the second input and I can access it from there.

```
<input name="input1" type="file" multiple>
<input name="input2" type="file" multiple>
```

Comment: your question is not really clear.

Comment: So I will explain to you what i want to do, if i have selected an image from the first input,  i want to access it from the second , this is my target .
@sancelot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inputs for files are special in that the file selection is not stored in the value attribute, hence `ngModel` won't work. You can reference each input by using a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars) like `#variablename`. Then, when the first input changes, you add the file selection to the second input with `(change)="input2.files = input1.files"`.

```
<input name="input1" type="file" multiple #input1 (change)="input2.files = input1.files">
<input name="input2" type="file" multiple #input2>
```

Try it out [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/RZ4K1RdMOBwQGft18GjI)

Comment: No , unfortunately it doesn't work , the second input still undefined

Comment: What exactly does not work? When you select one or multiple files in the first input, they will show up in the second one. see this plunker https://embed.plnkr.co/RZ4K1RdMOBwQGft18GjI/

Comment: Ok ,I will try it again, and I will show what I get, thanks for helping brother

Comment: thanks  it works perfectly and I have achieved what I want to do with it